# Tabulator (getData() on custom property sent in JSON like last_page?)

Tags: tabulator

getData() on custom property sent in JSON like last_page?

Is there a way to get at a custom property from the table object? I was thinking of sending in a property like last_page at the top level of the JSON that would hold the total record count. This would be handy for remote pagination information in the footerElement:. Can't really do the math with out the exact total.

e.g. Showing 1 to 10 of 13 rows

The 13 is an unknown with remote. I would like to send it in and d a getData("total_records") or something without having to add to every row object.

Comment: You should look at the ajaxResponse option of the table.  Return data from your server like, {lastPage: 3, rows: [{someField: "SomeValue}]}.  Then parse it with the ajaxResponse option and set a variable to your lastPage value.  (I don't have time to create a full example right now.  But, I think that should work for you.)http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/data#ajax-alter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return data from your server in whatever format you want.  But, you have to use the `ajaxResponse` parameter of Tabulator, so that you can change the format to what Tabulator requires.  http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/data#ajax-alter

For example, if your response returns json with some additional properties, but the property `data` contains the array of table information.  You could setup the `ajaxResponse` function like this,

```
function myRes(url, params, response){
  return response.data;
}
```

Here is an example using this, there are some additional properties, but the only relevant one for you is `ajaxResponse`.
https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/r319zaep/36/

Answer (score 0):

Built from what nrayburn-tech added does exactly what I was looking for. The console.log value could be used post dataLoad and populate a footer label now.

```
ajaxResponse: function(url, params, response){
    console.log(response.totalRecordCount);
    return response.rows;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisGo/4a2hdtcm/16/